# Issue using jest - Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I receive error using the following test case:

```
 Cannot read property 'weatherIconCode' of undefined
```

I am passing `weatherIconCode` to the component from the test case, but I do not understand why I get undefined.

Any ideas how to solve with a brief explanation is very welcome.

Component:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import IconWeather from '../../shared/icon/IconWeather'

class SummaryChartIcon extends Component {
  render () {
    const { cx, cy, payload: {weatherIconCode} } = this.props
    return (
      <svg x={cx - 10} y={cy + 20}>
        <foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>
          <IconWeather code={weatherIconCode} />
        </foreignObject>
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
export default SummaryChartIcon
```

test case:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import SummaryChartIcon from './SummaryChartIcon'

describe('<SummaryChartIcon />', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <SummaryChartIcon weatherIconCode={200} />
      )
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the right property for your component, in your case is `payload` which contain another object called with property `weatherIconCode`

If you change the code as follow it should work.

```
describe('<SummaryChartIcon />', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <SummaryChartIcon payload={{weatherIconCode: 200}} />
      )
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```